# Java android change color of actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Simply want to change the color of my actionbar!

So, when I google this, it appears pretty simple...

I've seen people propose this several times:

```
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#990000</item>
</style>
```

But I really cant get this to work. It doesn't do any thing different.. Actionbar is still black.
But exactly this seems to work for other people, so I dont understand..

When I try to put this:

```
    ActionBar actionBar;

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#990000"));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

in my onCreate, the app just crashes...

Edit: Okay I'm an idiot for posting way too soon...
Just had to put the actionBar code below the:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

It works now, sorry for posting before I tried that...

Comment: Can you post the log from Logcat of the crash you are experiencing?

Comment: @DavidArgyleThacker i can almost guarantee getActionBar returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The new Lollipop AppCompat library does not use `android:` namespace for theming. It is highly probable that you theming will work if you remove `android:` and do it like below:

```
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

The better way of doing is to use `Toolbar` instead of deprecated `ActionBar`. To do it like that, your theme should parent from NoActionBar theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

And you have to include `Toolbar` into your own layouts like below. That way you can set whatever background you want.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="#990000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply your theme to your entire app or individual activities on the manifest:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```